# Many to Many Hibernate Join Condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 3 table "A", "AB" and "B", where "AB" is a mapping table, i can make a lazy field of collection at A_Entity with this code

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "AB",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_id"))
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public Collection<B_Entity> getBEntities() {
    return b_entities;
}

public void setBEntitie(Collection<B_Entity> b_entities) {
    this.b_entities = b_entities;
}
```

my question is how if "B" has "applyToAll" field if set to true then it must selected in every "A" entities, in SQL i can do this with inner join below

```
INNER JOIN B ON AB.B_ID=B.B_ID OR B.Apply_to_all=true
```

Thanks

Comment: JPQL or CriteriaQuery? Also it would not harm if you provided something what you have tried already, how have you started to convert this query?

Comment: @pirho, i'm using both, jpql and criteriaquery. my question is more about persistence mapping. to be honest the above code is what so far i've been tried, because i can't find any example for my case. fyi i'm newbie at hibernate, jpa and spring, this is my first project